# Bad file descriptor error in Python (Error 9) on Raspberry

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am working with Python for the first time, and encountered the following issue, while running it on a Raspberry Pi Version B+ rev 2:

The code is supposed to set an interrupt on pin 22 (BCM), and when a button is pressed, halt the OS:

```
    # Import the modules to send commands to the system and access GPIO pins
from subprocess import call
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

# Define a function to keep script running
def loop():
    raw_input()


# Define a function to run when an interrupt is called
def shutdown(pin):
    call('halt', shell=False)

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM) # Set pin numbering to BCM numbering
gpio.setup(22, gpio.IN) # Set up pin 22 as an input
gpio.add_event_detect(22, gpio.RISING, callback=shutdown, bouncetime=200) # Set up an interrupt to look for button presses


loop() # Run the loop function to keep script running
```

The program runs fine when I call it like this:

```
python program.py
```

But if I put it in the background like this:

```
python program.py &
```

it works fine, until I do any another command (can be anything (eg. ls)).
Then it stops (but doesn't kill it).

I did a nohup output, and this is what I have in it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "haltButton.py", line 19, in <module>
    loop() # Run the loop function to keep script running
  File "haltButton.py", line 7, in loop
    raw_input()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Can anybody please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A background program can't do `raw_input()`. That's the whole point of being a background program: you give up user input so the shell (or some other program) can run and handle it.

If you just want to run forever until signaled, just find a different way of doing that. Almost *anything* will work, except `raw_input`. For example, you can loop over `time.sleep`, or `select.select` on some fd, or anything else you can think of except for trying to read from an fd that you closed.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, thank you!

Another question though: 
time.sleep works with a while loop right? So then it defeats the whole purpose of having interruption instead of a while loop that constantly checks the GPIO pin.

Comment: @WilhelmSorban: `time.sleep` doesn't work with a while loop, it works by asking the kernel not to run your program at all for the next 1 second (or however long) unless there's a signal.

Comment: @WilhelmSorban: Under the covers, that's not much different than `raw_input`, which includes a blocking `read` call on the standard input, which tells the kernel not to run your program at all until there's something to read on that file descriptor unless there's a signal.